# Recommended aspect ratio for android / smartphones?

Tags: c#, android, monogame, resolution, aspect-ratio

I'm making a game for android and would do it in 720p, but the phones got all different aspect ratios.
Also thinking about a ios and windows phone port later.

When the aspect ratio does not match, pretty much all I can do is making black borders, stretch it, or leave the part which does not make it out on the screen.
The game would be not as good when not the entire screen is visible, for example you see an enemy spawning later.

Which aspect ratio should I choose? On the techniques I stated above, maybe I just let the user decide, they are very easy to implement and they can choose the handicap which is at least annoying for them.

On 16:9 they will be only borders on the top and bottom, but at some aspect ratio somewhere in between, some would have them on the left and right.

Resolution itself is not important, trying to scale down with drawing to a renderTarget first.

Comment: Does not answer it. I said that I can not hide the overlapping part because stuff spawns on the edge.

Comment: Then please edit your question to request a strategy for how to handle the spawning of units across multiple aspect ratios. Maybe it's not just picking a different aspect ratio, but some other strategies you could use as well. See this related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51134/handling-different-aspect-ratios-for-a-multiplayer-game

Answer (score 0):

Depending on game type and graphical choices, showing a larger environment when the screen is larger than minimum size can range from harmless and good-looking (e.g. the same playfield with more audience around it in a team sport simulation, the same view of the car and the road with more sky and clouds above it in first-person 3D racing) to unacceptable (e.g. seeing more players in a team sport simulation, seeing incoming enemies earlier in a RTS or seeing a larger portion of the road from a different perspective in racing).

Letterboxing might not be exciting, but it surely beats stretching aspect ratio or damaging the balance of your game.